# Controlling the Spotify desktop app using Pywinauto in Windows

Tags: python, spotify, pywinauto

Is there a way to control the Spotify desktop app using pywinauto? Tutorials only show examples with simple apps like Notepad which have windows with titles. The Spotify app window doesnt have a title and I dont know how to create the window specification object in this situation,or to control anything in spotify. I can open the Spotify app using the code below but thats about how far I go.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application  
app = Application().start('Spotify.exe')
```

I am trying to specify and select a playlist on the left side panel of the Spotify windows app which contains saved playlists, then select play on any random song from the playlist window that pops up on the right.I tried to click on a playlist name called 'New Music' on the left panel by using the following code, which is still incomplete as I need another argument to specifically reference the playlist I need:

```
app.window(control_type='TextControl').click()
```

The only useable values I got from Inspect.exe for the item listed as "New Music" are `Name:New Music`, `ControlType:TextControl`, `ProcessId:3680`, and a list of Ancestors.

I couldnt use the `ProcessId` since every other playlist uses the same id and couldnt use the `Name` since it wont be a valid argument.

Comment: Have you read the Getting Started Guide? Have you tried Inspect.exe and UIA backend?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Yeh I couldnt find anything of help in the guide. Will look into Inspect.exe and UIA

Comment: Inspect.exe is mentioned in the Guide before window specification. Isn’t it highlighted enough?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I had initially used SWAPY but I've learnt more after looking into Inspect, which also shows the complete tree view. I am able to specify the window and have used `draw_outline()` to ensure i have the right window. I got stuck after that as I have no clue how to reference any of the tree items that I can see in inspect.exe. I'm quite new to python as well so I'm struggling translating the documentation examples to spotify. Will just keep trying.

Comment: Well, if you’re still stuck, please post small piece of code and the error output in the question body.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov thanks I have updated my question with more information

Comment: Sorry, this is not enough detailed. I need too much time to reproduce it fully.